# GatsbyJS: Search based on markdown files

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

Can anyone provide some hints how to solve the following problem with **GatsbyJS**:
I have a page, which is listing all the markdown files of the project, via this GraphQL query:

```
query ListQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark(sort: {fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC}) {
        edges {
            node {
                id
                html
                frontmatter {
                    date(formatString: "DD.MM.YY")
                    docs
                    path
                    tag
                    title
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm right, it's not possible to set a dynamic filter which is binded to the search input field.

Later on I found this: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-search-with-js-search/
I thought **js-search** could be the solution, but then I need a big .json file. The problem: It's more comfortable to work with markdown files. So this doesn't look like the right solution either.

I am thankful for help!

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-search-with-js-search/)

> Before we go through the steps needed for adding client side search to
>   your Gatsby website, you should be familiar with the basics of Gatsby

Markdown and GraphQL are used during **build phase**, during creating your static site.

During **run phase**, during client search you don't have access GraphQL/Markdown. They are not exist during user interaction with your site.

So for client search, you should create `need a big .json file`. If you will follow the doc, it will not be problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm very late to answer this question, but it might be somewhat helpful for others looking for it.

Before adding search to gatsbyjs web app you should have some idea how gatsby builds the app. You can check it in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/#:%7E:text=gatsby%20build%20creates%20a%20version,rehydrated%20into%20a%20React%20application.).

To add search you first need to create an index of all the markdown files. For creating an Index you can do it manually or can use search engines like aloglia, elastic search or lunr.js. If you want everything easy to manage you can go with aloglia which has a cap for free searches. If you want to go without spending any money you can go with [lunrjs](https://lunrjs.com/) .

What these search engines will do is that they will create a data layer above the graphql data layer which can be used during the run time. You can then create node which can be used to query the posts in the app.[This blogpost](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-add-lunr-search-to-your-gatsby-website/) explains setting up search in gatsby with details.